Creating a Finite Sized "Clique-based Network"
A clique based network is a network in which every node is in an identical environment, specifically in $m$ cliques of size $n$ for $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ (where a clique is a complete subgraph of a graph). Such a network only exists in theory, and I am trying to construct a finite sized graph that mimics its structure. The trouble I am having with this boils down to the following mathematical/algorithmic problem.
Fix $n,m,k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq 3,m\geq 2$. Does there exist a $l\in \mathbb{N}$ such that we can construct $\frac{m-1}{n}\cdot lm(m-1)^k(n-1)^{k+1}$ subsets of a set of nodes $\{n_i\}_{i\in [lm(m-1)^k(n-1)^{k+1}]}$ obeying the following constraints:
(1) For each subset $T_j$, $|T_j| = n$
(2) For each node $n_i$, $\sum_j \mathbf{1}\{n_i\in T_j\} = m-1$
(3) For all distinct $j$ and $j'$, $|T_j \cap T_{j'}| \leq 1$
(4) For all distinct $i,i'$, if $n_i$ and $n_{i'}$ are both in $T_j$ for some $j$, then $\lfloor i/n \rfloor \neq \lfloor i'/n \rfloor$
If such an $l$ exists, then there exist subsets that obey the above constraints. How would I go about constructing them explicitly?
Any help solving it would be appreciated. (If more background for the problem is requested it can be provided)
